# Disable /sales/order/history page

Tags: magento2

How can I disable the sales/order/history page? I would like to show a 404 page when a user goes to that page instead. I have disabled a content page before but haven't disabled a Magento specific before.

Even if I remove this page, it should automatically redirect to a 404 page. That's how it worked for the content pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Custom URL rewrite using from Admin only.

Use following steps:

go to Marketing >> SEO & Search >> URL Rewrites
click button `Add URL Rewrite` with following options.

[image]

Comment: Too easy! Thank you so much. Really Appreciate it.

Comment: welcome @SaraWhitmore.. glad to know it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a new module, `Vendor_DisableHistoryPage` inside `app/code/` - working directory would be `app/code/Vendor/DisableHistoryPage`

Now, lets create the basic files you need for a module:

Create `registration.php`:

```php
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_DisableHistoryPage',
    __DIR__
);
```

Create `etc/module.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_DisableHistoryPage">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Now, let's declare a plugin `etc/di.xml`

```php
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\History">
        <plugin name="disable_order_history_page" type="Vendor\DisableHistoryPage\Plugin\HistoryPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Write the plugin to throw 404 when history page controller is executed, `Plugin/HistoryPlugin.php`:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\DisableHistoryPage\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\History;

class HistoryPlugin
{

    /**
     * @throws NotFoundException
     */
    public function beforeExecute(History $subject): ResultInterface
    {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Page not found.'));
    }
}
```

Run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

Here is how it should look like after:

[image]